# DexArchieveBuilderException - Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I changed a class name of my project after which on running the app, I'm being showed this in "Message Build Gradle". I've tried undoing the name change but still it is being showed.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process D:\Wamiq_stuff\My_Android_work\AssignShare\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\5
Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/wamiqanwar/assignshare/login_page$3) does not match path (com/wamiqanwar/assignshare/Login_Page$3.class)
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing com/wamiqanwar/assignshare/Login_Page$3.class
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process D:\Wamiq_stuff\My_Android_work\AssignShare\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\5
```

Thanks for Reading!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean and rebuild the project. This problem probably happened because the app with **Instant Run** feature enabled is not rebuild after you've changed the code.